# Exponential not working in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
import math
from math import exp
dic_1 = {'x': [0.0005697499999999999, 0.00056825,0.00056825,0.00056825,0.00056825],'y': [-1.1e-05, 548],'z': [653,  672,150,590],'w': [653, 672,150,590]}
dic_1 = {key:[i*(exp(6)) for i in val] for key,val in dic_1.items()}
print dic_1
```

Currently Result looks like this

```
{'y': [-0.00022094090615506435, 11006.874233906841], 'x': [0.011443734661986173, 0.011413606356601392, 0.011413606356601392, 0.011413606356601392, 0.011413606356601392], 'z': [13115.855610841547, 13497.480812382113, 3012.83053847815, 11850.466784680724], 'w': [13115.855610841547, 13497.480812382113, 3012.83053847815, 11850.466784680724]}
```

But I want is

```
{'y': [0, 548000000], 'x': [569.75, 568.25, 568.25, 568.25, 568.25], 'z': [653000000, 672000000, 150000000, 590000000], 'w': [653000000, 672000000, 150000000, 590000000]}`
```

if I use `dic_1 = {key:[i*(10**3) for i in val] for key,val in dic_1.items()}`
I am getting the following result

```
{'y': [-11.0, 548000000], 'x': [569.75, 568.25, 568.25, 568.25, 568.25], 'z': [653000000, 672000000, 150000000, 590000000], 'w': [653000000, 672000000, 150000000, 590000000]}
```

Comment: Following from your previous question, I think you have mixed the output and the input. Do recheck it once again. (See the value of  key `'x'`)

Comment: I changed the Input and code as per my need.

Comment: Apart from that `exp(6)` gives `e` power 6 and not `10` power 6. For `10` power 6 you need `10**6`

Comment: dic_1 = {key:[i*(10**6) for i in val] for key,val in dic_1.items()} , I tried this and then went exponential but if input has exponential then I am getting different value.

Comment: I still don't understand why the first value in `'y'` must be 0. Can you clarify on that?

Comment: if you see my latest result of 'y' values (with 10**6, )..... the exponential value is coming as -11 but I am expecting '0'

Comment: Yep. I understand that. But why do you expect `0`. `-1.1e-05` multiplied by `10` power `6` is `-11` indeed.

Comment: I am not getting that formula but some how of my tool (data stream) can be able to produce that, there I just gave f(x) = x*1E6 as value conversion for numerical input box... it works .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of discussion in comments, I have finally understood your problem. The code can be written as

```
dic_1 = {'x': [0.0005697499999999999, 0.00056825,0.00056825,0.00056825,0.00056825],'y': [-1.1e-05, 548],'z': [653,  672,150,590],'w': [653, 672,150,590]}

def tester(key,value):
    if 'e' in str(value):
        return 0
    #elif key in ('x'):     # This was what you wanted last time. 
    #    return value       # I have commented it out to match output
    else:
        return (10**6) * value

newdic = {key:[tester(key,i) for i in value] for key,value in dic_1.items()}
print newdic
```

And the output as expected

```
{'y': [0, 548000000], 'x': [569.75, 568.25, 568.25, 568.25, 568.25], 'z': [653000000, 672000000, 150000000, 590000000], 'w': [653000000, 672000000, 150000000, 590000000]}
```

or we can also try this if we dont want parse any 'x' values .

```
def tester(key,value):
    if ('e' in str(value)) & (key not in ('x')):
        return 0
    elif key in ('x'):     # This was what you wanted last time.
        return value       # I have commented it out to match output
    else:
        return (10**6) * value

newdic = {key:[tester(key,i) for i in value] for key,value in dic_1.items()}
print newdic
```

And the output as expected

```
{'y': [0, 548000000], 'x': [0.0005697499999999999, 0.00056825, 0.00056825, -1.1e-05, 0.00056825, -1.1e-05, -1.1e-05, 0.0005697499999999999, 0.00056825, 0.00056825, -1.1e-05], 'z': [0, 0, 150000000, 590000000], 'w': [653000000, 0, 150000000, 590000000]}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. although I couldn't able to figure out why my GUI could able to apply f(x) = x*1E6, and I am not able to do the same in python. With the above mention code at least I can wrap the exponential values to '0'.

Comment: Yep there will be differences everywhere! Even I have faced many situations like that. All the best in future! :)

Answer (score 0):

exp(x) return e to the x power. I think you need 10**x instead:

```
...   key:[i*10**6 for i in val   ...
```